# Is it safe to abort this file-searching thread?

Tags: winforms, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-abort

First, the code:

```
lblFileNbr.Text = "?/?";
lblFileNbr.ToolTipText = "Searching for files...";
lock(_fileLock)
{
    _dirFiles = new string[0];
    _fileIndex = 0;
}
if(_fileThread != null && _fileThread.IsAlive)
{
    _fileThread.Abort();
}
_fileThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName) ?? ".";
        lock (_fileLock)
        {
            _dirFiles = GetImageFileExtensions().SelectMany(f => Directory.GetFiles(dir, f, _searchOption)).OrderBy(f => f).ToArray();
            _fileIndex = Array.IndexOf(_dirFiles, fileName);
        }
        int totalFileCount = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.*", _searchOption).Length;

        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            lblFileNbr.Text = string.Format("{0}/{1}", NumberFormat(_fileIndex + 1), NumberFormat(_dirFiles.Length));
            lblFileNbr.ToolTipText = string.Format("{0} ({1} files ignored)", dir, NumberFormat(totalFileCount - _dirFiles.Length));
        });
    });
_fileThread.Start();
```

I'm building a little image-viewing program. When you open an image, it lists the number of files in the same directory. I noticed when I open an image in a directory with a lot of other files (say 150K), it takes several seconds to build the file list. Thus, I'm delegating this task to another thread.

If, however, you open another image before it finishes searching for the files, that old count is no longer relevant, so I'm aborting the thread.

I'm locking `_dirFiles` and `_fileIndex` because I want to add some <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> key functionality to switch between photos, so I'll have to access those somewhere else (but in the UI thread).

Is this safe? There seems to be dozens of methods of dealing with threads in C# now, I just wanted something simple.

---

`fileName` is a local variable (which means it will be "copied" into the anonymous function, right?), and `_searchOption` is readonly, so I imagine those 2 are safe to access.

Answer (score 3):

> > Is it safe to abort this file-searching thread?

The short answer is **NO!**

It is almost never safe to abort a thread, and this advice applies even more when you might be executing native code.

If you can't cooperatively exit fast enough ( because it is your call to `Directory.GetFiles` that takes time ), your best bet is to abandon the thread: let it finish cleanly but ignore its results.

As always, I recommend reading [Joe Albahari's free ebook](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: Hrm...you could end up with dozens of open threads if I don't abort them though. That, and I'd need to write some special code to ensure the "callback" doesn't fire out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't safe to abort the thread using Thread.Abort(). But you could instead implement your own abort which could allow you to safely bring the thread to a close in a controlled fashion.

If you use EnumerateFiles instead of GetFiles, you can loop through each file as you increment a counter to get the total number of files while checking a flag to see if the thread needs to abort.

Calling something such as this in place of your current GetFiles().Length:

```
private bool AbortSearch = false;
private int NumberOfFiles(string dir, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, searchPattern, searchOption);
    int numberOfFiles = 0;
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        numberOfFiles++;

        if (AbortSearch)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return numberOfFiles;
}
```

You could then replace

```
_fileThread.Abort();
```

with

```
AbortSearch=true;
_fileThread.Join();
```

You'll achieve what you are with the current Thread.Abort(), but you will allow all threads to end cleanly when you want them to.

Comment: I was thinking about exactly that, but you'll notice I have a `.OrderBy` on there.. I think it'd have to go through all of them before it returns the first result, which would be the bulk of the time, and thus this wouldn't yield any benefit.... but now that I think about it, I suppose I could make it 2-pass, and fetch all the files first (via enumerate)...manually put them into a List and then sort afterwords.

Comment: I think that if you can turn both instances of your GetFiles into EnumerateFiles you will no longer have a single line of code that is taking a lot of time to execute and so should be able to abort rapidly. Perhaps you could even try to do it all within a combined loop (with the file counter) so you only need to loop through the file names once?

Comment: Yeah, I enumerate *all* the files and do the filtering manually, then I would only need to loop once. Perhaps I'll try that.